# Opening a empty session on other tty

Tags: tty, xinit

me@pop-os:~$ `xinit -- :2 vt3`

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux pop-os 6.6.6-76060606-generic #202312111032~1702306143~22.04~d28ffec SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon D x86_64
Kernel command line: initrd=\EFI\Pop_OS-ebdf8099-3515-474a-86ae-0b54f95c95b2\initrd.img root=UUID=ebdf8099-3515-474a-86ae-0b54f95c95b2 ro loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false quiet splash
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/alex/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.2.log", Time: Sat Jan 13 14:24:31 2024
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 3 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/alex/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.2.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I also tried this from tty3 itself. It starts the xserver with a black screen and then closes immediately.

Here is the [log](https://pastebin.com/raw/JstAqxDa)

How can I start a new empty session in a new tty?

I'm using the latest Pop_OS! (22.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

i think it is permission related problem
try running:

```
sudo xinit -- :2 vt3
```

Ensure that your user has the necessary permissions to access the virtual console. You can add your user to the tty group:

```
sudo usermod -aG tty your_username
```

Try a Different TTY:
Instead of using vt3, you can try starting X on a different virtual terminal. For example:

```
sudo xinit -- :2 vt4
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150887/discussion-on-answer-by-crazegi-contact-opening-a-empty-session-on-other-tty); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.